# KenBurnsView how to set max scale?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-kenburnsview

I'm using [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) to add animation to my image.
Is it possible to set the max scale programmatically ? Small images are too zooming.

Comment: I don't know, but now I want to find an excuse to use a `KenBurnsView`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can . For this purpose you have to implement your own TransitionGenerator. 
Like given blow .In following code you can call SetMinRectFactor() to set minimum zoom sacale.

```
public class BackgroundTransitionGenerator implements TransitionGenerator 
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_TRANSITION_DURATION = 9000;
  private static final Interpolator DEFAULT_TRANSITION_INTERPOLATOR = 
  new LinearInterpolator();

private long transitionDuration;
private Interpolator transitionInterpolator;
private Transition lastTransition;
private RectF lastDrawableBounds;
private boolean forward;
private float MIN_RECT_FACTOR=1.0f;

public void SetMinRectFactor(float f)
{
    MIN_RECT_FACTOR=f;
}
public BackgroundTransitionGenerator() {
    transitionDuration = DEFAULT_TRANSITION_DURATION;
    transitionInterpolator = DEFAULT_TRANSITION_INTERPOLATOR;
}

@Override
public Transition generateNextTransition(RectF drawableBounds, RectF viewport) {
    float drawableRatio = getRectRatio(drawableBounds);
    float viewportRectRatio = getRectRatio(viewport);
    RectF startRect;
    RectF endRect;
    if (drawableRatio >= viewportRectRatio) {
        float w = drawableBounds.height() * viewportRectRatio;
        float h = drawableBounds.height();
        startRect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        endRect =generateRandomRect(drawableBounds,viewport); //new RectF((drawableBounds.width() - w), drawableBounds.height(),drawableBounds.width(), h);
    } else {
        float w = drawableBounds.width();
        float h = drawableBounds.width() / viewportRectRatio;
        startRect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        endRect =generateRandomRect(drawableBounds,viewport); //new RectF(0, drawableBounds.height() - h, w, drawableBounds.height());
    }

    if (!drawableBounds.equals(lastDrawableBounds) || !haveSameAspectRatio(lastTransition.getDestinyRect(), viewport)) {
        forward = false;
    }
    forward = !forward;

    if (forward) {
        lastTransition = new Transition(startRect, endRect, transitionDuration, transitionInterpolator);
    } else {
        lastTransition = new Transition(endRect, startRect, transitionDuration, transitionInterpolator);
    }

    lastDrawableBounds = new RectF(drawableBounds);
    return lastTransition;
}

private static boolean haveSameAspectRatio(RectF r1, RectF r2) {
    return (Math.abs(getRectRatio(r1) - getRectRatio(r2)) <= 0.01f);
}
private RectF generateRandomRect(RectF drawableBounds, RectF viewportRect) {
    float drawableRatio = getRectRatio(drawableBounds);
    float viewportRectRatio = getRectRatio(viewportRect);
    RectF maxCrop;

    if (drawableRatio > viewportRectRatio) {
        float r = (drawableBounds.height() / viewportRect.height()) * viewportRect.width();
        float b = drawableBounds.height();
        maxCrop = new RectF(0, 0, r, b);
    } else {
        float r = drawableBounds.width();
        float b = (drawableBounds.width() / viewportRect.width()) * viewportRect.height();
        maxCrop = new RectF(0, 0, r, b);
    }

    float factor = MIN_RECT_FACTOR ;

    float width = factor * maxCrop.width();
    float height = factor * maxCrop.height();
    int widthDiff = (int) (drawableBounds.width() - width);
    int heightDiff = (int) (drawableBounds.height() - height);
    int left = widthDiff;
    int top = heightDiff;
    return new RectF(left, top, left + width, top + height);
}

private static float getRectRatio(RectF rect) {
    return rect.width() / rect.height();
}
```

}